# How do I remove placeholding values from a two dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an int[ ][ ] a that contains both positive and negative integers. I want to copy only the positive integers into another array, int[ ][ ] result.
Here's my attempt:

```
for( int r = 0; r < a.length; r ++ )
        {
            int aC = 0;
            for( int resC = 0; resC < result[r].length; resC++ )
            {
                while (a[r][aC] < 0)
                {
                    aC++;
                }
                result[r][resC] = a[r][aC];
                aC++;
            }
        }
```

When I run the program it crashes on line 6 quoting a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3` error. When I run the debugger I can see that it works so long as r = 0.

I feel like I'm missing something blindingly obvious but after staring at it for an hour I still can't find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why have 3 loops? Just loop your 2 dimensions and copy positive values:

```
for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < a[r].length; c++)
        if (a[r][c] > 0)
            result[r][c] = a[r][c];
```

---

Unless of course you want to condense the values (question didn't say, but code attempt seems to indicate). Or did you also want to truncate?

```
  Input              Copy            Condensed        Truncated
-1  1   2           0  1  2           1  2  0           1  2
-1  -1  3    ==>    0  0  3    ==>    3  0  0    ==>    3
4   -1  5           4  0  5           4  5  0           4  5
```

Here is a version with truncation:

```
int[][] result = new int[a.length][];
for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < a[r].length; c++)
        if (a[r][c] > 0)
            count++;
    result[r] = new int[count];
    for (int c = 0, cRes = 0; c < a[r].length; c++)
        if (a[r][c] > 0)
            result[r][cRes++] = a[r][c];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no bounds checking on

```
a[r][aC]
```

so

```
while (a[r][aC] < 0)
```

will fail.

Also as you will now have uneven sized arrays, it would be better to to add to an ArrayList, and then convert to an array afterwards if necessary.

Something like

```
ArrayList <Integer> posValues = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
for( int r = 0; r < a.length; r ++ )
{
        for( int c = 0; c < a[r].length; c++ )
        {
            if (a[r][c] > 0)
            {
                posValues.add (new Integer (a[r][c]));
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: But when while (a[r][aC] < 0) fails wouldn't the program advance to result[r][resC] = a[r][aC];? I was under the impression that the error I recieved indicated that I was calling a value where there wasn't one. Could you please clarify your answer? Thanks.

Comment: if the value of `aC` is greater than the length of the sub-array a[r], then it will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - thats what I mean by `no bounds checking`

Answer (score 0):

When we reach the inner `for` loop,
we don't have any guarantees about `result[r]`,
and so `r` may very well be out of bounds.
Instead of this:

> ```
>     for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
>         int aC = 0;
>         for (int resC = 0; resC < result[r].length; resC++) {
> ```

The code will be *safer* like this:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
        int aC = 0;
        for (int resC = 0; resC < a[r].length; resC++) {
```

Because, we know that `a[r]` will be within bounds.

But this is not nearly enough.
The innermost `while` loop is also likely to try to access an index out of bounds, in fact it's inevitable when you have at least one negative value.
Actually you need to invert the looping logic there,
instead of iterating over indexes in result,
it will make more sense to iterate over indexes in the source.
Like this:

```
    for (int r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
        int resC = 0;
        for (int aC = 0; aC < a[r].length; aC++) {
            if (a[r][aC] < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            result[r][resC++] = a[r][aC];
        }
    }
```

Finally, with variables renamed, it becomes a lot easier to understand what the code is trying to do:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < source.length; row++) {
        int targetCol = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < source[row].length; col++) {
            if (source[row][col] < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            target[row][targetCol++] = source[row][col];
        }
    }
```